# Is there a way Spotlight indexes my Skim bookmarks/notes ?

Tags: pdf, spotlight, bookmarks, skim

I find Skim is a great pdf file reader and want to spend a great deal of time adding notes and bookmarks to some of the pdf files I have.

I know Spotlight indexes pdf files but it doesn't seem to index my Skim bookmarks. 
(I just created a bookmark in Skim and search for that bookmark in Spotlight. No results).

I may force Spotlight to index net.sourceforge.skim-app.skim.bookmarks.plist (it is where bookmarks are stored) ?

What do you think ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you search for a bookmark you created longer ago in Skim, does it show up? It might just take time for Spotlight to index the files.

Comment: I created two bookamrks. Two days later I searched for them using spotlight. No answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've found+tested:

In Skim:

> - File - Export -> Skim notes.
> - You now have one .skim file with your annotations only + their pages number.

Skim notes are indexed by Spotlight.

Source: [here](https://macademic.org/2012/12/20/searchable-pdf-annotations-automating-conversion-to-skim-notes/)

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, the developer who made Skin will have to add the support to be searched in Spotlight themselves, as they have to create a spotlight importer (basically, a plugin) in order for spotlight to look at things inside unsupported filetypes.

Answer (score 0):

Use **CMD + SHIFT + /** to search your bookmarks (or just click the Help menu item).